# Oracle - Fill null values in a column with values from another column

Tags: sql, null, obiee

I am using Oracle 11.1.1.9.0 and my goal is to fill the Null values with the first NOT NULL values in "Raw Materials" column by each product i.e A, B and C in Product column.  An example table and the intended result are illustrated at the end of this request.

None of the code sets in below works:

CODE 1:

```
IFNULL(Raw Materials,
       First_value(Raw Materials) OVER (PARTITION BY Product))
```

CODE 2:

```
IFNULL(Raw Materials, 
        First_value(Raw Materials) OVER (PARTITION BY Product 
                       RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))
```

CODE 3:

```
COALESCE(lag(Raw Materials ignore null) OVER (partition by Product), 
         Raw Materials)
```

CODE 4:

IFNULL(Raw Materials, EVALUATE('LAG(%1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY %2)' AS varchar2(20), Raw Materials, Product))

Note: IFNULL function does work in the environment.  It was tested with IFNULL(Raw Materials, '1') and it resulted in all null values becoming 1 in Raw Materials column.

Thank you.

```
+---------+----------+      +---------+----------+  
| product | material |      | product | material |
+---------+----------+      +---------+----------+
| A       |          |      | A       | Apple    |
| A       |          |      | A       | Apple    |
| A       |          |      | A       | Apple    |
| A       |          |      | A       | Apple    |
| A       | Apple    |      | A       | Apple    |
| B       |          |      | B       | Orange   |
| B       |          |      | B       | Orange   |
| B       |          |  =>  | B       | Orange   |
| B       |          |      | B       | Orange   |
| B       | Orange   |      | B       | Orange   |
| C       |          |      | C       | Banana   |
| C       |          |      | C       | Banana   |
| C       |          |      | C       | Banana   |
| C       |          |      | C       | Banana   |
| C       | Banana   |      | C       | Banana   |
+---------+----------+      +---------+----------+

Left is the example table data. Right is the intended result.
```

The below link "Oracle code environment" shows the code environment and samples of Oracle Logical SQL function.
[Oracle code environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlWDW.png)

Oracle Logical SQL manual: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/biee/BIEUG/appsql.htm#CHDDCFJI

Comment: Oracle does not have an `IFNULL` function. Your code would have worked if you'd swapped `IFNULL` for `COALESCE` in either of the first two options.

Comment: Which row do you consider "first"? I see no `ORDER BY` in your expressions. Can there be different materials per product? If so, please add such an example in your request.

Comment: @MT0 
Thanks for reaching out.  I am working under OBIEE using their logical SQL and IFNULL is one of the function provided.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner

Thanks for reaching out.  In this case I am only looking at one component per product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you say that you are looking for some "first" value, your sample data suggests that you just want all same products to have the same material:

```
update mytable m1 set material = 
(
  select min(material)
  from mytable m2
  where m2.product = m1.product
);
```

If you just want to select this data. Then you can use this:

```
select product, min(material) over (partition by product)
from mytable;
```

According to the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/sqlref.htm#BIEMG678) it seems OBIEE uses a special syntax for analytic window functions (`e.g. MIN() OVER()`):

```
select
  product,
  evaluate('min(%1) over (partition by %2)', material, product)
from mytable;
```

You must enable this by seeting the `EVALUATE_SUPPORT_LEVEL` accordingly.

(I hope I got this right. Otherwise read the docs on this and try something along the lines for yourself.)

Comment: Thanks again Thorsten.

In Oracle OBIEE, when I put MIN () or MAX() around Raw Materials, it result in error.  Could it be because MIN() or MAX() don't process string character in Oracle OBIEE environment?

Comment: The Problem seems to be the analytic function `MIN OVER`. I've added a query that might be a solution in OBIEE.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt iteration and reference on EVALUATE_SUPPORT_LEVEL documentation.

Since an error code prompted EVALUATE_... was not supported, I will have to reach out to my system administrator for his help to enable EVALUATE_SUPPORT_LEVEL support and test your suggested solution.

Meanwhile, how did you generate your suggested link, in which when opened directly shows the relevant content on the page?  Instead of be opened at the top of the page.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/sqlref.htm#BIEMG678

Thank you

Comment: That is an anchor (# in url). When on a site you can sometimes click a link that leads t some place down that site. This is part of the URL. In this example I clicked such a link or got directed there by Google (I don't remember), so the #BIEMG678 became part of the url.

Answer (score 1):

For your dataset, you could simply do a window `MAX()` or `MIN()`:

```
NVL(Raw_Materials, MAX(Raw_Materials) OVER(PARTITION BY Product))
```

*If* you have a column that can be used to order the rows (I assumed `id`), you can use `LAG()` with the `IGNORE NULLS` clause:

```
NVL(Raw_Materials, LAG(Raw_Materials IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY id))
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out GMB.

I tried the 2 suggested codes in OBIEE environment and it didn't work.  I tested NVL() function with a similar setup and it also ran into error.  I surmise NVL() is not understood by Logical SQL in Oracle.

I also tried the following code, it resulted in error as well.  Thoughts on where the errors could be in?


IFNULL
(
Raw Materials, EVALUATE
(
'LAG(%1, 1) over (PARTITION BY %2)' AS varchar2(20), Raw Materials, Item Number
)
)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query,We are using First value analytic function nullif, COALESCE, etc work on row level not column level.

```
with temp as (select 'A' product,NULL raw_material from dual union all
select 'A',NULL from dual union all
select 'A',NULL from dual union all
select 'A',NULL from dual union all
select 'A','APPLE' from dual union all
select 'B',NULL from dual union all
select 'B',NULL from dual union all
select 'B',NULL from dual union all
select 'B',NULL from dual union all
select 'B','ORANGE' from dual union all
select 'C',NULL from dual union all
select 'C',NULL from dual union all
select 'C',NULL from dual union all
select 'C',NULL from dual union all
select 'C',NULL from dual union all
select 'C','Banana' from dual)
select   a.*,FIRST_VALUE(raw_material IGNORE NULLS) 
     OVER (partition by product ORDER BY product) first_product from temp a;
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Bhanu Yadav.

The sample chart is a simplified version of my case, which has dozens of products and they change periodically.  Thereby manually coding each item code might not be applicable in my case.  However I really appreciate your suggested codes, which might be a resolution to a future case!

Comment: Hi @JonathanChan, I have used hard-coded values only for working code and that is working as temp table. The main code is below the with clause where I am using first_value and partition by clause with the order by  to differentiate the value. in select   a.*,FIRST_VALUE(raw_material IGNORE NULLS) 
     OVER (partition by product ORDER BY product) first_product from temp a;

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although OBIEE calculated measure couldn't run this code, it definitely works on standard SQL environment.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have an `IFNULL` function. Your code would have worked if you swapped `IFNULL` for `COALESCE` in either of your first two code snippets:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       COALESCE(
         raw_material,
         FIRST_VALUE(raw_material)
           IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( PARTITION BY product )
       ) AS updated_raw_material
FROM   test_data t;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> PRODUCT | RAW_MATERIAL | UPDATED_RAW_MATERIAL
> :------ | :----------- | :-------------------
> A       | null         | Apple               
> A       | null         | Apple               
> A       | null         | Apple               
> A       | Apple        | Apple               
> B       | null         | Orange              
> B       | null         | Orange              
> B       | null         | Orange              
> B       | null         | Orange              
> B       | Orange       | Orange              
> C       | null         | Banana              
> C       | null         | Banana              
> C       | null         | Banana              
> C       | null         | Banana              
> C       | null         | Banana              
> C       | Banana       | Banana
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3eee0b42a028da6be9eb0cdb831784a9)*

Comment: Thanks again MT0

The suggested code results in error.  Wonder which part of the code is not understood by Logical SQL in Oracle.

I tried sticking with Oracle's Logical SQL with the below code, and it also resulted in error.  Do you see where the error could lie in?

IFNULL (Raw Materials, EVALUATE ( 'LAG(%1, 1) over (PARTITION BY %2)' AS varchar2(20), Raw Materials, Item Number ) )